# Why 032*2 = 52 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am interesting in understanding why `032*2` returns `52` in JavaScript.

I have a feeling that `032` could be interpenetrated as `octal notation` but I could not find a proper reference to it.

Could you please:

- Provide me an explanation with references.

Thanks in advance your help on this.

Comment: RE: your feeling did you google `octal notation javascript`? Top 3 results for me all explain it and MDN is amongst them.

Comment: thanks for posting a related questions/answer, but I believe my question is not duplicated... I also eed link/reference to some documentation other than an explanation.

Comment: 032 = (3*(8^1)+2*(8^0)) = ((3*8)+2*1)=(24+2)=26.So , 032*2 = 52

Comment: questions asking us to recommend an off site resource are also off topic.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for commenting, I was not aware of this rule about link to external resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript 5.1 specifies some extensions to Numeric literals [in its annex](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1):

> The syntax and semantics of 7.8.3 [Numeric literals] can be extended as follows except that this extension is not allowed for strict mode code:
>
> ```
> NumericLiteral ::
>    DecimalLiteral
>    HexIntegerLiteral
>    OctalIntegerLiteral
> OctalIntegerLiteral ::
>    0 OctalDigit
>    OctalIntegerLiteral OctalDigit
> ```

This concludes that any number which starts with a `0` and is followed by `OctalDigit`s can be considered an octal one. However, this is **not** allowed in strict mode.

Answer (score 5):

[Numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) starting with `0` are *Octal*. So, `032 === 26`.

To convert it into Base-10/*Decimal* number use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with *radix* 10.

```
parseInt('032', 10) * 2; // 64
```

From MDN Docs:

> If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following:

1. If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.
2. **If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).**  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.
3. If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

Answer (score 2):

> **Octal interpretations with no radix**
>
> Although discouraged by ECMAScript 3 and forbidden by ECMAScript 5, 
>   many implementations interpret a numeric string beginning with a leading 0 as octal.The following may have an octal result, or it may have a decimal result.
>   Always specify a radix to avoid this unreliable behavior.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Oh, that is interesting. I didn't know ES5 forbade it.. learn something new each day I guess.